# Transitivity in angles between vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Consider 3 unit vectors ${\bf a}$, ${\bf b}$ and ${\bf c}$. We know that ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf b}=0$ and ${\bf a}\cdot {\bf c}=1$. Can we say something about ${\bf b}\cdot {\bf c}$?

Also, when dealing with this problem can we consider WLOG that one of the vectors (e.g., ${\bf a}$) is $[1~~ 0~~ 0~ \cdots ~0]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're unit vectors, then $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}=1\implies \mathbf{a}=\mathbf{c}$, so $\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{a}=0$

Comment: Thank you!  I could prove that only under the assumption that ${\bf a}=[1~~0~~\cdots~0]$. Can I consider that WLOG?

Comment: yes, you can always pick a basis in which $\mathbf{a}=[1,0,0,\cdots]$